# Prove $\left.{\partial X\over \partial Y}\right|_Z=-\frac{\left.{\partial Z\over \partial Y}\right|_X}{ \left.{\partial Z\over \partial X}\right|_Y}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms

> $$\left.{\partial X\over \partial Y}\right|_Z=-\frac{\left.{\partial Z\over \partial Y}\right|_X}{ \left.{\partial Z\over \partial X}\right|_Y}$$

The above is an identity frequently used in thermodynamics when $X$,$Y$, and $Z$ satisfy $\phi(X, Y, Z) = const$ for some function $\phi$. My thermodynamics book drives the identity like this: Let's assume the constaint can be solved for $Z$, so we have $Z(X, Y, \phi)=const$. The differential of $Z$ is written as
$$0 = dZ = \left.\frac{\partial Z}{\partial X}\right|_{Y,\phi} dx + \left.\frac{\partial Z}{\partial Y}\right|_{X,\phi} dy + \left.\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \phi}\right|_{X,Y} d\phi$$
Now we set $d\phi=0$, and devide the above equation by $dy$, and identify $dx/dy$ as $\left.\frac{\partial X}{\partial Y}\right|_{Z,\phi}$. Finally we drop the $\phi$ in the subscripts of partial derivatives (this is just a convention). Then we get the identity. Is this acceptable as a mathematical proof? If not, I'd like to know how to prove it. And I'd like to know whether there is a rigorous way to justify $dy/dx=\left.\frac{\partial X}{\partial Y}\right|_{Z,\phi}$ in terms of "differential forms" or in terms of "differentials in calculus".

Comment: Most people would not consider what you described as a proof. I assume $X$ and $Y$ are both functions of some variable $t$?

Comment: @Potato, they are usually not a function of a variable $t$. In thermodynamics, you can think them as like a 2-manifold in 3d Euclidean space. The equation $Z(X,Y)=const$ defines the manifold in the space of $X$,$Y$ and $Z$.

Comment: Then from the implicit function theorem, $X$ is locally a function of $Y$, and you can use the chain rule on $Z(Y,X(Y))$ to get $\frac{\partial{Z}}{\partial Y}+\frac{\partial Z}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial Y}=0$ and solve.

Comment: Your equation implicitly assumes $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial Z}$ doesn't vanish, and this is exactly what is need to get the implicit function theorem to work.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake! The constraint is not $Z(X, Y) = const$!. It should be $\phi(X, Y, Z) = const$ for a function $\phi$. I'll edit my question.

Comment: The answer is essentially same. You use the implicit function theorem and the chain rule in the same way.